# The usage of Form on Laravel 5.1 shows only text

Tags: laravel-5.1

I use the laravelcollective/html form, and i opend the form

```
{!! Form::open(['role' => 'form']) !!}
```

and closing

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and of course the contect inside, the problem is that the output is like text

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/Users/public" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
```

Comment: what do you mean, i created the form, but that is how it is supposed to show? or show the form, you tell me ?

Comment: You mean that when the page loads it shows the HTML markup rather than the actual form?

Comment: there is no problem in your form but make sure you are using it in `filename.blade.php`, `.blade.php` is important

Comment: or you can always use simple html5 forms in any case :)

Comment: Would you check the source code, the code is being escaped this is why the browser renders it and display it as text. Follow @Adamnick recommendations and ensure the Blade engine parses the file.

Comment: Did you install Form Facade in your project?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your form but make sure you are using it in `filename.blade.php`, `.blade.php` is important or you can always use simple html5 forms in any case :)